# Using NativeAPI with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, windows, api, native

I'm trying to understand how to use `Native API` (like `NtOpenFile`) with `visual studio`.

I have downloaded `Windows Driver Kit` but i'm unable to compile a working example.

My goal is to use `Native API` in native subsystem but for the first time i want to POC in user land.

Have you a working example (On Windows 7) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [NtOpenFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432381(v=vs.85).aspx) function isn't intended to be called from user code.  Rather, it's more for things like device drivers or other extensions to the operating system.

For user code, you should be using the [Windows API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API).  For Windows 8 and later, you also have the [Windows Runtime or WinRT API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime).  The traditional Windows API is more C oriented and can be a little clumsy for a beginner to use from C++.  If you don't need compatability with Windows 7 or earlier OSes, then the WinRT API can be easier to use as it is more object-oriented.

There are plenty of books on these APIs as well as all the [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh920508(v=vs.85).aspx).